# Why am I not getting the value of the field rather than the field itself?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I'm trying to do web scraping for the first time using BeautifulSoup and Python. The page that I am trying to scrape is at: http://vesselregister.dnvgl.com/VesselRegister/vesseldetails.html?vesselid=34172

```
client = request('http://vesselregister.dnvgl.com/VesselRegister/vesseldetails.html?vesselid=34172')
page_html = client.read()
client.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html)

identification = page_soup.find('div', {'data-bind':'text: name'})
print(identification.text)
```

When I do this I simply get an empty string. If I print out simply the identification variable I get:

```
<div class="col-xs-7" data-bind="text: name"></div>
```

[This is the line of html that I am trying to get the value of, as you can see there is a value A LEBLANC there in the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hgIP.png)

Comment: This is an Ajax-powered site, all the data is loaded by Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

browser=driver.get('http://vesselregister.dnvgl.com/VesselRegister/vesseldetails.html?vesselid=34172')

find=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identificationCollapse"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]')

print(find.text)
```

output:

```
A LEBLANC
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can achieve the same goal. However, I've used selector in my script which is easy to understand and has got less chance to break unless the html structure of that website is heavily changed. Try this out as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://vesselregister.dnvgl.com/VesselRegister/vesseldetails.html?vesselid=34172')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.quit()
item_name = soup.select("[data-bind$='name']")[0].text
print(item_name)
```

Result:

```
A LEBLANC
```

Btw, the way you started will also work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://vesselregister.dnvgl.com/VesselRegister/vesseldetails.html?vesselid=34172')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.quit()
item_name = soup.find('div', {'data-bind':'text: name'}).text
print(item_name)
```